# Why did the resistance go up on my inductor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I was testing an inductive load on a frequency analyzer, and apparently the resistive component went up from 2 to 25 ohms from 0 to 20kHz. Is there any reason for this or am I taking my measurements wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: well, a proportionally frequency-dependent resistance is an inductive load?

Comment: The frequency analyzer broke it up into reactance and resistance. Apparently the resistive component went up.

Comment: You can try switching to a parallel L-R circuit model and compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eddy currents circulating inside the core produce resistive losses but only circulate when there is AC to induce current flow in the core.

(The difference being energy consumed due to reactance is recovered some time in the future when the energy is released back into the circuit by the inductance/capacitance whereas energy consumed by resistances not recovered. The meter detects this difference when instantaneous readings are averaged out and examines how much power consumption was cancelled out over time and how much was not versus the total amount of power flowing.